# curl runs fine in the terminal, getting 419 error with httr

Tags: r, httr

I have a curl that runs fine in the terminal, produces a response. It ends with:

```
--data-raw 'field1=123456&_token=mytoken'
--compressed
```

I've set up my `data` list as follows:

```
data = list(
  `field1` = '123456',
  `_token` = 'mytoken'
)
```

Then I make the following call to POST:

```
httr::POST(url = 'url', 
       httr::add_headers(.headers=headers), 
       httr::set_cookies(.cookies=cookies), 
       body = data
       #,encode = 'raw'
       )
```

What does `raw` mean in the curl `--data-raw`? Does this mean I would set `encode='raw'`? I've tried every iteration of `encode` I can think of.

When I try to run in R I get:

```
Status: 419
Content-Type: application/json
```

If I turn around and run the original curl in the terminal, everything works.

Any ideas about what I might be specifying incorrectly?

---

I used httpreq.com and tried the working curl from the terminal and the adapted httr code from R (replacing the url with the httpreq.com recording endpoint). I noticed two differences:

1. First, the recording for R lacks one cookie parameter defined in `cookies = c()`.
2. Second, the "User-Agent" is different. For the terminal it records as `"libcurl\/7.64.1 r-curl\/4.3 httr\/1.4.2"`. For the R script, it records as `"Mozilla\/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/....`. This is what I specified in `headers = c(`User-Agent`="...")` because this is what I found in the original curl. Do I need to change the agent for R?

Comment: `--data-raw` would be the same as `encode="form"` for httr. Give that a try.

Comment: Thanks. That was confusing me. Unfortunately, `encode="form"` produces the same result.

Comment: A 419 can mean "authentication timeout" So there may be a problem with your headers or cookies. It's really impossible to say without documentation for the API endpoint.

Comment: OK, thanks for thinking about it. I'm confused by the timeout since I can fail in `httr` and turn around and succeed with the original curl in the terminal.

Comment: Well, are those the only two CURL parameters you are using? Also, some endpoints screen based on user agent. It's also not clear how you've formatted your headers or cookies. There are tons of things that could be off. Can can try sending both commands to a site like https://httpreq.com/ rather than the actual URL and comparing the result to find any differences.

Comment: Yes, just a bunch of `-H` that go in `headers = c()` , including one `-H 'Cookie:` that goes in `cookies = c()`. Thanks for sharing the web resource. I did not know about that. I noticed two differences. I'll add the details to the post for space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up calling `system()` on the original curl that worked in the terminal. This let me work in R where I'm more comfortable, but I could not get a httr solution working.